# AS3 call php page with javascript in it?

Tags: php, javascript, actionscript-3

I'm trying to call a php script/page that has some javascript calls in it, from AS3.
I'm using the regular

```
var varSend:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://my_www/script.php");
varSend.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;(...)
```

My php page has some javascript. The php passes some variables obtained in POST to my JS script, which connect to a 3rd party app.

Now my problem is, i can call the script from AS3 without any problem, but when i do so, it seems like the JS is never running. My question is, if you call a php script/page in POST from flash, is the JS embed in that page running ??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass that JavaScript to the browser to run it. In ActionScript it's just a string.

In an AIR app  you can create an HTML control to run the JS in.

In a browser app, you can send the string to some of your own JS code, in the containing HTML, using `ExternalInterface`.

Comment: Yes it is in an AIR app. What do you mean by "create an HTML control and run the JS in" ? I understand the HTML control part but "run the JS in" ??

Comment: He means the HTMLViewer class or StageWebView class available in various versions of Adobe AIR.  Both allow you to render a webpage from within the context of air.

Comment: My question is, would the JS embed in that page, run in the HTMLViewer ? Is HTMLViewer html5 compliant ?